# Determine and display which of those years were or will be leap years

Tags: python-3.x, loops

The problem i'm having is this:
I'm a relative n00b and I have an assignment asking me to work out leap years, which I have done (I hope...).

The things is, is it's asking me to give a range of years to print out. So it asks to enter from which year you want to start, and then it asks how many years you want to check. So if I say start at 1990 the next input is asking how many years to check. If I say 10, it'll check from 1990 to 2000 to see which years were leap years, but I don't know how to do that.

Please help?

Attached is the code.

```
  start_year = int(input("Which year do you want to start with?     "))
  check_year = int(input("How many years do you want to check?      "))#This is the part I'm struggling with.


  for i in range(start_year):
                            
  if (i % 4) == 0 or (i % 100) == 0 or (i % 400) == 0:
        print(i,"is a leap year")
    else:
        print(i,"is not a leap year")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call range(x), it will iterate from 0 to x.
You have to call range(x, y+1) to iterate from x to y. Note that y+1 will not be iterated through.
Example:

```
for i in range(1, 8):
    print(i)
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

So, for your task, to check 10 years from 1990 to 2000 **(not including 2000)** you'll need:

```
for i in range(start_year, start_year + check_year):
```

It should print:

```
1990 is not a leap year
1991 is not a leap year
1992 is a leap year
1993 is not a leap year
1994 is not a leap year
1995 is not a leap year
1996 is a leap year
1997 is not a leap year
1998 is not a leap year
1999 is not a leap year
```

Comment: YAY! That's great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The [range(n)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function gives you values ranging from 0 to n-1. You can however specify a start and stop value:

```
start_year = int(input("Which year do you want to start with?     "))
check_year = int(input("How many years do you want to check?      "))#This is the part I'm struggling with.

for i in range(start_year, start_year+check_year):
                            
    if (i % 4) == 0 or (i % 100) == 0 or (i % 400) == 0:
        print(i,"is a leap year")
    else:
        print(i,"is not a leap year")
```

Comment: Perfect! It's amazing how something so small, has had me agonizing for a whole day!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

```
start_year = int(input("Which year do you want to start with?     "))
check_year = int(input("How many years do you want to check?      "))#This is the    part I'm struggling with.


for i in range(start_year, start_year+check_year):
                        
  if (i % 4) == 0:
    if (year % 100) == 0:
      if (year % 400) == 0:
         print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
      else:
         print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
    else:
       print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
  else:
    print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
```

This way you would like not doing other verifications if the first assumption is true.

To iterate with

```
range()
```

you have to enter begin index and end index. With your code you are iteration over your input value. Say 2010, you will iterate over 2010 values.

Don't hesitate to accept as an answer. Others responses works too :)
I just made some re-adjustement to your code to avoid useless assertions.